# Getting icon number in here rest place api

Tags: regex, here-api

I'm working with windows phone apps and using here rest place api to get data and I looking to prepare my own icon for transportation category data (since i will only get that data from place api)

so from what i read in json

```
position: [ 37.77704 , -122.39494 ]
distance: 1241
title: Caltrain-San Francisco
averageRating: 0.0
category: { Public transport }
icon: http://download.vcdn.nokia.com/p/d/places2/icons/categories/11.icon
vicinity: 700 4th St<br/>San Francisco, CA 94107
having: [ ]
type: urn:nlp-types:place
href: http://demo.places.nlp.nokia.com/places/v1/places/8409q8yy-a7395cccbfc4474ba469f3ddc03e041b;context=Zmxvdy1pZD00OWQxZDY0Zi0zODc5LTVlNDAtOWY4ZC04ZGFmNWMyMGZhZDFfMTM4OTg4NDQxMzUxNV8wXzM1MjkmcmFuaz0w?app_id=lp3VaO8uhOFe0akZ4J1m&app_code=JwL7MNaSarML92oqEDshAg
id: 8409q8yy-a7395cccbfc4474ba469f3ddc03e041b
```

there is

```
 icon: http://download.vcdn.nokia.com/p/d/places2/icons/categories/11.icon
```

and by clicking it i can see that is car/bus transportation icon, so is there any documentation about what category in transportation icon?because when i change it into 12.icon it showing different icon that i can tell that is not transportation related icon

and what is regex for stripping that http? since i only need number 11 from that code to make it the same as my assets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this answer I originally suggested to use the category as a key for icons instead of the icon URL itself.

Unfortunately, this is not a good idea either, since categories (as well as icon URLs) might change at any time in the future without prior notice.

The only exception of this are [the eternal categories described in the documentation](http://places.demo.api.here.com/places/static/doc/public/#topics/categories.html). So theoretically, after retrieving a search result, you could [request the *categories* resource for that location](http://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/categories/places?app_id=demo_qCG24t50dHOwrLQ&app_code=NYKC67ShPhQwqaydGIW4yg&at=52.521,13.3807) (you could use the search center from the response as input for the categories endpoint) which gives you all available categories at that location, together with child-parent relationship. Then, for each place in the search result, you could traverse the tree up. You might then end up at an eternal category and have a custom icon for that one.

For instance *transport* which is the parent of *public-transport* is one of those categories.

However, this might not be feasible, since it would require a second request after each search request. And it’s even not completely future proof, since it’s as well not guaranteed that there’s always a 1:1 relationship between categories and icons.

Comment: yes, at first I was going to use category id but if you try to navigate to 0.0000,109.3333 it is in indonesia my country and the category is different with the same icon like category with id:"transport" have same icon as you json up there.

Answer (score 0):

Try `\d+(?=\.icon)`  - one or more digits followed by (but not including) the characters `.icon`

For safety you may want to add `^` as well - `\d+(?=\.icon)^`  - one or more digits followed by (but not including) the characters `.icon` and followed by the end of the string.

You may find [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/) useful for this sort of thing.